# " when we close the app so its showing like given in example for giving the direction or any other info, message." in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, navigation, direction

I am trying to create an Compass. but i want when we close the app is showing like small popup app on any other app Screen like:- google map showing the direction.

please help me to find out the plugin in flutter.

or please share any other example.

[image: navigation Screen]

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget.

Comment: Read this medium article https://medium.com/@ashishgarg1998/how-to-create-home-screen-app-widgets-in-flutter-ce3458f3638e